# How do I solve for Ksp

Tags: solubility, solutions

The problem gives that the solubility of Silver dichromate is $8.3\times10^{-3} g/100mL$. I need to find $K_{sp}$ which is supposed to be $2.8\times10^{-11}$.

$K_{sp}$ is $\ce{[Ag+]^2[Cr2O7^{2-}]}$

I changed the $8.3\times 10^{-3}$ from g/mL to mol/L and got $1.9\times 10^{-8}$.

Silver dichromate breaks into 2 Ag and one dichromate.

So that would be $(2 \times 1.9\times10^{-8})^2 \times ( 1.9\times10^{-8})$

That's what I did but it's not giving me the right answer. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem gives that the solubility of Silver dichromate is $\mathrm{8.3\cdot10^{-3} g/100\,mL}$.
>
> […]
>
> I changed the $8.3\cdot10^{-3}$ from g/mL to mol/L and got $1.9\cdot10^{-8}$.
>
> […] Were am I going wrong here?

Was the solubility given in $\mathrm{g/100\,mL}$?

$$\mathrm{8.3\cdot10^{-3} g/100\,mL = 8.3\cdot10^{-2}\,g/L = \frac{8.3}{431.72}\,mol/L = 1.92\cdot10^{-4}\,mol/L}$$

Comment: Thanks. I was doing something stupid going from mL to L.

Comment: My pleasure! Blame it on the late night or the early morning ;)

Comment: Haha, yea. Think I pull way too many of those (late nights). I'm lucky the internet makes it easy t find a fresh set of eyes to give a second look.

Comment: Yes, I'm not on CST. It's 08:00 over here.

Comment: It's just about 3:30am here. Kind of the only time it's quiet in here so...